# Windows Azure WebPi install fails for Nov 2011 release

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, web-platform-installer

whatever I try, it seems the webpi installer for Azure november 2011 release keeps failing.  This it the log file I get from webpi:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: ttps://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767054
DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttps://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767054 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:36:49 GMT
Location: ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:48 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Dec 2011 18:40:06 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "a08f4a4fb5cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 438735100400000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:49 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\542864071.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Dec 2011 22:58:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "d12faab0eab9cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 791472300300000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:50 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1338951197.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Nov 2011 18:16:33 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "4bfbe4b5b9fcc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 791472300300000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:51 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\664384761.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/toolsproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/toolsproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 00:01:01 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1d2b74cdceb6cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 438776600300000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:51 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1956869252.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttps://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:02:13 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "265bd232f88cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 438735100400000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:51 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\903079739.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: ttp://www.orchardproject.net/privatedrops/orchardfeed.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttp://www.orchardproject.net/privatedrops/orchardfeed.xml responded with 404
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1245
Via: 1.1 EUR-PRXY-10
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET


DownloadManager Error: 0 : Error loading downloaded product file: 'System.InvalidOperationException: XML file contained no products
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.LoadProducts(XmlElement rootElement, XmlNamespaceManager nsm)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.LoadFromXmlInternal(LineInfoDocument xmlDoc, Boolean loadEnclosures)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.LoadFromXml(TextReader xmlTextReader, Boolean loadEnclosures)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.LoadFromXml(String xmlFile, Boolean loadEnclosures)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.ProductManager.Load(Uri productFileUrl, Boolean filterByArchitectureAndOS, Boolean loadEnclosures, Boolean useCachedVersion, String cacheDirectory, Architecture architecture, Int32 majorOS, Int32 minorOS, Int32 majorSP, Int32 minorSP, Int32 osType)'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from ttp://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : ttp://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 203
Via: 1.1 EUR-PRXY-11
Expires: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:36:52 GMT
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:37:51 GMT
Location: ttp://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual entry products: WindowsAzureToolsVS2010
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Azure SDK for .NET - November 2011 (WindowsAzureToolsVS2010) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual navigation to product 'WindowsAzureToolsVS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'WindowsAzureToolsVS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsAzureSDK' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsAzureSDKOnly' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETFramework35' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsAzureEmulator' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'ASPNET' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'StaticContent' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASProcessModel' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETExtensibility' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'RequestFiltering' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASNetFxEnvironment' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'ISAPIExtensions' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'ISAPIFilters' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'DefaultDocument' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'CGI' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'UrlRewrite2' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'FastCGIUpdate' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'PowerShell' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product PowerShellMsu does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'IISManagementConsole' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASConfigurationAPI' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'DirectoryBrowse' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPErrors' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPRedirection' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPLogging' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'LoggingTools' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'Tracing' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'RequestMonitor' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'MVC3' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETFramework4' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsImagingComponent' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC3Installer' for product 'MVC3'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010' for product 'WindowsAzureToolsVS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'VSVWD2010Feature' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No SQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No MySQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'ttp://download.microsoft.com/download/D/F/4/DF442AB0-FAAE-44FF-A04E-F41E72FE6B6F/WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe' to: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49.tmp' to: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010\580DFFB79499C7427AD38C84E632FFFF39C3FBCC\WindowsAzureTools.VS1007.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC3Installer\7a15ca7a49ac8a9edfe71ac0873a8aa38338c029\AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe instead of downloading from http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/1/F31EF055-3C46-4E35-AB7B-3261A303A3B6/AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - November 2011'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010\580DFFB79499C7427AD38C84E632FFFF39C3FBCC\WindowsAzureTools.VS1007.exe /quiet /norestart /log C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall.txt'. Process Id: 8972
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - November 2011' is -2147023293
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - November 2011' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - November 2011 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure SDK for .NET - November 2011'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure SDK for .NET - November 2011 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC3Installer\7a15ca7a49ac8a9edfe71ac0873a8aa38338c029\AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe /q /log C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\mvc3_install.htm'. Process Id: 9192
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer' is 0
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 4
```

Trying to install the Azure Tools manually as suggested below, fails and returns the following log file:

```
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:55]: Burn v3.6.2228.0, path: C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010\580DFFB79499C7427AD38C84E632FFFF39C3FBCC\WindowsAzureTools.VS1007.exe, cmdline: ''
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Initializing string variable 'ProductShortName' to value 'Windows Azure Tools - November 2011'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - November 2011'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010_-_November 2011_20111215214856.log'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010\580DFFB79499C7427AD38C84E632FFFF39C3FBCC\WindowsAzureTools.VS1007.exe'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Detect 2 packages
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 1
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Registry value not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0', Value = 'InstallDir'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: File not found. Path = '\VWDExpress.exe'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting numeric variable 'VWDEXPRESS_IDE_FILE' to value 0
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:56]: Setting numeric variable 'VSDEVENV' to value 1
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:57]: Detected package: CctSetup.Shared, state: Absent, cached: No
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:57]: Detected package: CctSetup, state: Absent, cached: Yes
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:48:57]: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Plan 2 packages, action: Install
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Condition '(VSDEVENV AND DEVENV_PROPLUS) OR VWDEXPRESS_IDE_FILE' evaluates to true.
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_CctSetup.Shared' to value 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010_-_November 2011_20111215214856_0_CctSetup.Shared.log'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_CctSetup.Shared' to value 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010_-_November 2011_20111215214856_0_CctSetup.Shared_rollback.log'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Planned package: CctSetup.Shared, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_CctSetup' to value 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010_-_November 2011_20111215214856_1_CctSetup.log'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_CctSetup' to value 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010_-_November 2011_20111215214856_1_CctSetup_rollback.log'
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Planned package: CctSetup, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ux requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:25]: Apply begin
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:28]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\.be\WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe'
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:28]: Registering bundle dependency key: {3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}, version 1.6.41103.1601
[1B48:2A0C][2011-12-15T21:49:28]: Moving payload from working path 'C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\CctSetup.Shared' to path 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601\WindowsAzureTools.VSCore.VS100.en-us.msi'
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:28]: Applying package: CctSetup.Shared, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601\WindowsAzureTools.VSCore.VS100.en-us.msi, arguments: ' IGNOREDEPENDENCIES="{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}"'
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Removing cached package: {10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{10EC9A93-A581-4063-A051-0F66D47EBC92}v1.6.41103.1601\
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute apply.
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Removing bundle dependency key: {3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}
[1B48:2E24][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Removing cached bundle: {3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3975541a-8609-49c4-94d7-10af6af23833}\
[1718:2A34][2011-12-15T21:49:32]: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643 restart: No
```

Comment: The log does not show anything specific to the Azure tools & SDK. It just shows that your client has cached version of the most recent product list catalog. Plus I wonder how did you get to a "December 2011" release, as the most recent release is November 2011?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the log file to find a more specific error: `C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsInstall.txt`. Error code -2147023293, which means a fatal installer error, is too generic.

Also, you can try invoking the cached installer manually:
`C:\Users\christoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2010\580DFFB79499C7427AD38C84E632FFFF39C3FBCC\WindowsAzureTools.VS1007.exe`. This would actually launch the installer with the UI, so it can give you more hints on the failure.

Comment: Thanks kateroh.  I tried installing manually as suggested.  Updated my original post with the log file information.  Not sure if that provides you with something more useful though.  Reinstalling my machine is really not an option at this point in time, so hope to resolve without having to do so.

Comment: Can you run the installer from the cached location directly? It might give you more info than the log file.

Comment: Still not resolved - only option that is left is to reinstall my machine, which I hate to do just because of Azure.  Install experience is horrible.